# How can I use the COUNT value obtained from a call to mkqlite()?

Tags: sql, database, matlab

I'm using [mksqlite](http://mksqlite.berlios.de/) to create and access an SQL database from matlab, and I want to get the number of rows in a table. I've tried this:

```
num = mksqlite('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable');
```

, but the returned value isn't very helpful. If I put a breakpoint in my script and examine the variable, I find that it's a struct with a single field, called 'COUNT(_)', which seems to actually be an invalid name for a field, so I can't access it:

```
K>> class(num)

ans =
struct

K>> num

num = 
    COUNT(_): 0

K>> num.COUNT(_)
??? num.COUNT(_)
                    |
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.

K>> num.COUNT()
??? Reference to non-existent field 'COUNT'.

K>> num.COUNT
??? Reference to non-existent field 'COUNT'.
```

Even the MATLAB IDE can't access it. If I try to double click the field in the variable editor, this gets spat out:

```
??? openvar('num.COUNT(_)', num.COUNT(_));
                                              |
Error: The input character is not valid in MATLAB statements or expressions.
```

So how can I access this field?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the problem is that mksqlite somehow manages to create an invalid field name that can't be read. The simplest solution is to add an AS clause to your SQL so that the field has a sensible name:

```
>> num = mksqlite('SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM myTable')

num = 
    cnt: 0
```

Then to remove the extra layer of indirection you can do:

```
>> num = num.cnt;

>> num

num =
     0
```